# Enabled and disabled checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

This is my checkbox and text box:

```
<td> <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" onclick="enable('<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>')" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>>

<td> <input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>" disabled /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>" disabled> </td>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
function enable(id) {
var disabled = !document.getElementById('haha').checked;
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled = disabled;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = disabled; }
```

my question is why this is only works on first row, i checked first checkbox the textbox will be enabled and then i unchecked first checkbox and checked 2nd and others that textbox still disabled.. how can i fix this?

Comment: how nice if you can remove php and provide a fiddle

Comment: "why this is only workds on first row", `id`'s are unique if you more than checbox with the same id `#haha` it will work for the first one.

Comment: yeah thanks. you're right my checkbox has the same id #haha but different values. how can i fix that? i tried getElementByid('haha').value, but it can't work.

Comment: Please edit your question into a snippet (click the [<>] button) and remove all PHP since it is irrelevant to the question and actually looks like you need to fix the ID handling

Comment: If it has same id rather than ID, pass this object and get the value and then get id and pass to dependent elements for it id.

Answer (score 1):

You could use just one function:

```
function toggle(someId) {
    document.getElementById(someId).disabled = !document.getElementById(someId).disabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the following:

```
function testEna() { 
  var dis = this.checked;
  document.getElementById("nama"+this.id).disabled=dis;
  document.getElementById("ket"+this.id).disabled=dis;
}
window.onload=function() {
  var ena = document.querySelectorAll(".enabler");
  for (var i=0;i<ena.length;i++) {
    ena[i].onclick=testEna;
    ena[i].onclick(); // run now too
  }
}
```

using

```
<input type="checkbox" class="enabler" id="<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your ID's but the disable and enable checkbox code is like this :

```
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("some_id").disabled= false;

}

function disable() {
    document.getElementById("some_id").disabled= true;
}
```

Comment: He used the checked boolean of the checkbox correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using same id twice .With out changing id u can use this. But u should update the parament i.e Rather than passing id you should pass this object

```
function enable(pobj) {
var id = pobj.value;
var disabled = !pobj.checked;
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled = disabled;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = disabled;
}
```

Preferably usage of same id is not recommended.

For reference you can check https://jsfiddle.net/uw5f001q/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you question exactly, But it's good to use jQuery for this. I have try something with this. See below jsfiddel link

```
jsfiddle.net/ravipateldhg/5c7rdt0a
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
function EnableDisable(id) {
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled =false;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = false;
var disabled = !document.getElementById('haha').checked;
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled = disabled;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = disabled; }
```